# Sonos Music Service: Diagnostics for CustomSD

Tags: sonos

I am currently developing a SMAPI service. I registered a customsd with my PLAY:1 speaker and I can see the PLAY:1 communicating with my service. I can see a 'getLastUpdate' request and my response, but on the Sonos Control (PC) I just see "Unable to browse music - there was a problem connecting to ." Is there any way to view more detailed diagnostics?

Answer (score 0):

A big of digging revealed the following useful endpoints:

```
http://<PLAY:1 IP>:1400/support/review
http://<PLAY:1 IP>:1400/status
```

It seems that the log of interaction with my customsd service can be found here:

```
http://<PLAY:1 IP>:1400/status/controllers -> ControllerConsoleLogInfo
```

Comment: Now going to http://<PLAY:1 IP>:1400/status/controllers just shows some basic controller information?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. I wonder if there is another way of debugging...